# Как вставить разделитель между ссылками (anchor)?

Tags: html, css, anchor

Есть две ссылки нужно чтобы они были в одну линию и между ними был знак `|`:

```
<div>
  <a href="URL">Служба поддержки</a>
  <a href="URL">задать вопрос</a>
</div>
```

С первой проблемой справился заключив их в `div`, а в CSS прописав:

```
display: block;
```

но как поставить этот символ между ними?

Comment: Все ссылки еще в один Flex div и между ними этот самый знак

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инлайн (фиксированный отступ):

```css
div > a, div > span {
 display: inline-block;
}

div > span {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>Служба поддержки</a>
  <span>|</span>
  <a>Задать вопрос</a>
</div>
```

Flex (фиксированный отступ):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

div > a, div > span {
 display: block;
}

div > span {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>Служба поддержки</a>
  <span>|</span>
  <a>Задать вопрос</a>
</div>
```

Flex (динамическое распределение):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div > a, div > span {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>Служба поддержки</a>
  <span>|</span>
  <a>Задать вопрос</a>
</div>
```

*Отступы:*

*В примерах 1 и 2 их можно регулировать при помощи `padding` или `margin`, указав в качестве таргета `span`, который содержит символ `|`.*

*В примере 3 отступы выставляются автоматически в зависимости от ширины родительского элемента `div` и настроек свойства `justify-content` ("space-around", "space-between", etc.).*

Comment: <div> <a href="URL">Служба поддержки</a><a href="URL">задать вопрос</a></div> а куда вставить то что вы написали?

Comment: @АлександрКочеров не очень понимаю Ваш вопрос, я поменял `p` на `div`, возможно Вам так проще будет сориентироваться

Comment: Больше спасибо)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div>
    <span>Служба поддержки</span>
    <span>|</span>
    <span>задать вопрос</span>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня сейчас <div> <a href="URL">Служба поддержки</a><a href="URL">задать вопрос</a></div> а куда вставить то что вы написали?

Comment: <div>
    <a href="URL">Служба поддержки</a>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="URL">задать вопрос</a>
</div>

Comment: Спасибо большое)